# Fluent API and building a 1:* relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-5, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables that have a 1 to 1..* relationship (meaning there will always be a record in the 'Status' table for a specific ID.

```
|Area|                |      Status     |
------                -------------------
|[Key]  ID |  ---->   |[Key]     ID     |
|      Name|          |[Key] Start Date |
                      |      End Date   |
```

I have the relationships built in my datalayer as follows.

Area

```
HasMany(s => s.Statuses)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id);
```

Status

```
HasRequired(a => a.Area)
   .WithMany(s => s.Statuses)
   .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id);
```

I have a generic 'AllIncluding' method that I use to gather the associated data.  in the debugger I can view the query and copy/paste to my Oracle database and execute.  It works as I'd expect and returns the appropriate number of rows.
The issue is that after execution in the debugger I browse through the recordset and find an entirely different set of data (a reduced set).

My thought is that it's because I have the keys defined as described in the diagram.  I can create errors regarding `... the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'` and also modify the recordset returned in the debugger by simply modifying the key on the Status table. 
This seems to indicate that the record relationship is attempting to remove duplicates in the Status table to create the Join?  I have attempted to recreate this in Oracle by doing a `group by trunc(start_date)` or other similar queries but cannot hit the exact rows returned result.
It has only confirmed my suspicion that the mapping and relationship defined in Fluent API must be wrong, but I'm not sure how to properly represent this.

Ultimately I'd simply like to create a 1 -> 1..* relationship in Fluent API.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see the class definitions. It seems that `Status` in reality is a junction class between `Area` and some status table that stores the "real" statuses, otherwise a many-to-many relationship seems more appropriate. But it's really hard to piece together from your description what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> It has only confirmed my suspicion that the mapping and relationship defined in Fluent API must be wrong

1. Be very careful when mapping relationships with Fluent API. Specifically the `With` method overloads used must match exactly the presence / absence of a navigation property. `WithRequired()` and `.WithRequired(a => a.Statuses)` are totally different. Use the former when you don't have navigation property, and the later otherwise. In your case you used wrongly the parameterless overload.
2. Always configure relationships in one place. The relationship is one thing involving two entities - there is no need to duplicate it in two places, and more importantly, it's error prone. Currently you have two definitions, one correct (for `Status`) and one incorrect (for `Area`). The net effect is that EF considers them to be two different relationships, which in turn leads to incorrect results.

So, either remove the code from `Area` and leave the code in the `Status` as is:

```
HasRequired(s => s.Area)
    .WithMany(a => a.Statuses)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id);
```

or remove the code from `Status` and use the following in the `Area`:

```
HasMany(a => a.Statuses)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Area)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id);
```

Comment: I attempted to remove the relationship from the Area table but I started to receive an error that the Area_Id value could not be found.  I understand it's due to the relationship not being defined so added back the .HasForeignKey() clause.

Comment: I think you may be on to something because I changed the key in my Status table to include others and am seeing new results

Comment: Based on what you have shown, there must be no `Area_Id` column in the table, because by your setup the `Status.ID` should be the FK to `Area`. Hope you also used something like `HaskKey(s => new { s.Id. s.StartDate }` in `Status` configuration. Anyway, without seeing the exact entity classes and the full configuration there is nothing more I can say.